# Laravel equivalent for User::all() function

Tags: php, laravel, api

Guys I have problem with `Laravel` `api`.

In my Controller, when I use `collection` `$teacher` then everything is fine but i need filtered data so when I use collection `$teachers` it gives me error. The error is `Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::mapInto();`

I want filtered data

```
    $teachers = DB::table('users')->where('role', '=', 1);
    $teacher = Users::all();
    return UserResource::collection($teachers);
```

I have tried this

```
$teachers = DB::table('users')->where('role', '=', 1)->get();
$teachers = DB::table('users')->where('role', '=', 1)->get()->toArray();
```

so I need solution

this is my Resource

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class User extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please attach your UserResource class code.

Comment: i edited my post  @Itzhak Avraham

Comment: Did you mean `class UserResource extends JsonResource` ?

Comment: In the top I gave alias like this use App\Http\Resources\User as UserResource;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$teachers = DB::table('users')->where('role', '=', 1);
$teacher = Users::all();
return new UserResource($teachers);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working but with this $teachers = DB::table('users')->where('role', '=', 1)->get();   I tried many ways but anyway your answer is the most helpful and i choose your answer as correct

Comment: happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about yours, but in my environment those lines of code work just fine. Try update your Laravel, using `composer update` command.

Comment: @NurbekBoymurodov I've edited my answer. What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: latest version 6.13.1

Answer (score 0):

`return UserResource::collection(User::where('role', '=', 1)->get());` This should work for you, can you try?

**Update**

you can still join tables with `eloquent`, but if you really want to use `DB::Table()`

then you have to specify your `toArray()` method like so.

```php
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        // return parent::toArray($request);
        return [
            'role' => $this->role,
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }
```

and `return UserResource::collection(DB::table('users')->where('role', '=', 1)->get());` will give you the result.

Comment: how can I make join table

Comment: I need DB::table